# MSAccess VBA - How to sort values in a Listbox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an MS Access list box that is being populated through DAO Recordset.  When the data is displayed the values are not sorted. The code that I have is not working.

```
Dim sqlString As String
sqlString = "SELECT ReportName FROM MetadData.ReportDB_Test ORDER BY " & Me.ListReports.Value & " ASC;" 
Me.ListReports.RowSource = sqlString
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` needs a column name, not a value.

Comment: Thanks! found a snippet code from "TheAceMan1" URL > https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1677888

Answer (score 0):

If you're just setting the rowsource of a listbox, there's no need to use VBA. Just set the `rowsource` property of the listbox to the SQL you need (you can even use Access's query builder).

Comment: I'm able to make it work in connecting to SQL without creating a link table.